# Page not accepting user on login even though user is valid

Tags: php, authentication, dreamweaver

I have been having some problems regarding the user login feature on the site I am making at the moment. I have created a login form table on the index.php page and told it to go to userindex.php if the login is valid or loginfail.html if it is not. Then using dreamweavers page authorization tool I have protect the page userindex.php and told it to redirect unauthorized users back to index.php

The problem I am having is that once someone enters correct username and password details and presses submit they are sent to index.php . It's as if they are sent to userindex.php and then not authorised. However after login typing the address for userindex.php reveals the page complete with the users information as if they have been approved.

Here's the code for the two pages regarding this user login issue

index.php

```
    <?php
        // *** Validate request to login to this site.
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
          session_start();
        }

        $loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
          $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['UsernmaeBox'])) {
          $loginUsername=$_POST['UsernmaeBox'];
          $password=$_POST['PasswordBox'];
          $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
          $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "Userindex.php";
          $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "loginfail.html";
          $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
          mysql_select_db($database_dbname, $dbname);

          $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Username, Password FROM SGUsers WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s",
            GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

          $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $Newsograph) or die(mysql_error());
          $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
          if ($loginFoundUser) {
             $loginStrGroup = "";

            if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
            //declare two session variables and assign them
            $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
            $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

            if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
              $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
            }
            header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSucenter code here      if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
```

userindex.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
```

Many thanks for reading. I've spent ages trying to figure it out and didn't think dreamweaver would make it so confusing! Thanks.

Comment: that's a lot of code for login and there's even no trap for sql injection. anyway why don't you try to comment out `header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); ` and try to echo the sessions variable to check if they hold any values. if they do hold the necessary values then you have something wrong with your if log in checker.

Comment: Great I'll have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible typos here. You have UsernmaeBox instead of UsernameBox. Unless of course you meant to do that.

```
if (isset($_POST['UsernmaeBox'])) {
      $loginUsername=$_POST['UsernmaeBox'];
```